# How can I help Typescript infer generic parameters for a PropertyDecorator factory function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-types

Say I have a generic decorator factory like this:

```js
declare type PropertyDecorator = (target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) => void;

// ^^^ Note: PropertyDecorator should be available as a built-in type with experimental decorators enabled.

export type Transformer<T, U> = (value: T) => U;

function PropertyTransformer<T, U>(to: Transformer<T, U>, from: Transformer<U, T>): PropertyDecorator {
  return (target, propertyKey) => {
    // Do some decorator stuff...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to restrict type `T` to be whatever type the decorated property happens to be (i.e. `T extends typeof target[propertyKey]`)?

Comment: Can you include the type `PropertyDecorator`? You can do it, but how depends on how you are typing it

Comment: PropertyDecorator should be a built-in type when experimental decorators are enabled. I'll go ahead and update the question with it's definition in case it helps.

Comment: I think you can do it, I'll check and post an answer if I manage to do it

Comment: It seems TS does not compute the inner call of the decorator normally, so it can't infer the type. You can propose this to be part of the language

Comment: I manage to get it correctly typed, but only explicitly by receiving a `<Foo, 'key'>` where `Foo` is the class I'm using the decorator.